# Can't install packages such as dplyr or devtools sessionInfo()

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm having trouble installing some packages. I previously installed data.table and had no problems. Now, when trying to install dplyr and devtools I get the following message:

```
Installing package into ‘[file path]’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.repo.bppt.go.id/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.repo.bppt.go.id/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning message:
package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

I am not exactly sure how to handle this.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Try a different repository, e.g. `install.packages("dplyr", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com")`

Comment: Not exactly.  I was suggested by Carl Witthof under #1 but I wasnt so obvious to me as to how to make it work.

Comment: The community will decide, but I agree with you that in order to work as a FAQ, that answer should contain this kind of suggestion. I'll think about it.

Comment: also try put sessionInfo() in your question